# Is it possible to use windows users for database login?

Tags: windows, authentication, database, user-accounts

I would like to know if there is any database management system (DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...) that allows me to use Windows user accounts for logging in.

I know that Tortoise SVN can do it, but I haven't found anything for a database server.

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 always uses the host systems security for identification and authentication.

So if you run db2 on a windows server anyone logging in will need a userid and password which is valid in the servers domain.

If they are logged in on the domain already they should not need to log in again.

And believe it or not Microsofts SQLServer also uses the standard Microsoft Windows domain user ids :-)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to a tutorial or the part of the DB2 documentation that explains how to setup DB2 in a domain? And is that functionality limited to the commercial edition?

Also I found something for MySQL, too, but only for their commercial version:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-authentication-plugin.html

Comment: DB2 requires you to set up a couple of "special" windows user ids, "db2admin" etc. otherwise its just a case of allocating normal windows user ids and granting them access from within db2 to the tables they require.